# Need help in hosting the laravel project using nodejs chat system

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, server, hosting

Hi everyone i am having a problem hosting the website made in `laravel(php)` and chat system in NodeJs. I have done this using `wamp` server and running node server in my local pc computer. Now i am trying to put those in online, i uploaded in `public_html/www` folder, the `laravel` part worked but the chat built in nodejs showing js error saying websocket.

I have no idea how to make it run online. can you give me some clue how to solve this.

Comment: is it working fine on your development machine?

Comment: yes Siraj running fine in my laptop

Comment: what is the error log you are getting